# C++ GTKMM, getting a weird output in a text-buffer

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm new to Gtkmm and trying to load a txt-file into a Text-Buffer. When I start my program I get a output like this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGKvq.png)

My code for filling the Text-Buffers looks like this:

```
void ExampleGui::fill_buffers()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/User/Documents/Gui/test1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    char *output = NULL;
    while ((getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        output = line;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);

    m_refTextBuffer1 = Gtk::TextBuffer::create();
    m_refTextBuffer1->set_text("Welcome!\nClick the button Show Text to start.");

    m_refTextBuffer2 = Gtk::TextBuffer::create();
    m_refTextBuffer2->set_text(Glib::convert_with_fallback(output, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1"));

}
```

How can I fix that wrong output and why do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the assignment `output = line` followed by `free(line)`.

Because `output` points to the same memory as `line` that means `output` becomes invalid.

Either don't free the memory until you're done with the string, or *duplicate* the string in `line` (which the assignment *doesn't* do).